# Headers In A Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview

This may seem like a simple question but I have looked around and can't find a straightforward answer. My app is a to-do list app and I would like to separate my `UITableView` into 3 sections, tasks, lists, and favourites.

I would like the headers to look like this:

[image: Headings]

And currently my app looks like this:

[image: My App]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the following methods in your `UITableViewController`.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 1 {
        return "first section title"
    }
    return "second section title"
}
```

You might need to adjust the following methods to consider that there a multiple sections now:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
    ...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
}
```